# How to append objects to a key inside JS array?

Tags: javascript

I have this array :

```
var res_data = [
    {"id": "1", "text": "AAA", "category": "food", "value": "1"},
    {"id": "2", "text": "BBB", "category": "food", "value": "2"},
    {"id": "3", "text": "CCC", "category": "drinks", "value": "3"}
];
```

I want to get this

```
{
  "food": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "text": "AAA",
      "category": "food",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "text": "BBB",
      "category": "food",
      "value": "2"
    }
  ],
  "drinks": [
    {
      "id": "3",
      "text": "CCC",
      "category": "drinks",
      "value": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried to do so by iterating and set the "category" value - as a key , inside a new array, like this :

```
    var res = [];
    $.each(obj, function () {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty("category")) {

            res[this['category']] = this;

            console.log(this['category']);

        }
    })
```

but the "food" index is keep overriding....

```
 drinks:{id: "3", text: "CCC", category: "drinks", value: "3"}
 food: {id: "3", text: "CCC", category: "food", value: "2"}
```

Comment: `append` mean what?.The expected output is wrong

Comment: I think your expected output should be `drinks=[{id: "1", text: "AAA", category: "drinks", value: "3"}]
 food=[{id: "2", text: "BBB", category: "food", value: "2"},
      {id: "3", text: "CCC", category: "food", value: "2"}]`.

Comment: Hey, thanks, i want to map the object by categroy, and to create a new object with the correct values...

Comment: @NarendraJadhav - YEAH , that's what i'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for array.

> ES5

```js
var arr = [{
      "id": "1",
      "text": "AAA",
      "category": "food",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "text": "BBB",
      "category": "food",
      "value": "2"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "text": "CCC",
      "category": "drinks",
      "value": "3"
    }
  ],
  outpt = {};

arr.forEach(function(item) {
  if (!outpt.hasOwnProperty(item.category)) {
    outpt[item.category] = []
  }
  outpt[item.category].push(item)
});

console.log(outpt)
```

> ES6

```js
let arr = [{
      "id": "1",
      "text": "AAA",
      "category": "food",
      "value": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "text": "BBB",
      "category": "food",
      "value": "2"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "text": "CCC",
      "category": "drinks",
      "value": "3"
    }
  ],
  outpt = {};

arr.forEach((item) => {
  if (!outpt.hasOwnProperty(item.category)) {
    outpt[item.category] = []
  }
  outpt[item.category].push(item)
});

console.log(outpt)
```

Answer (score 4):

A common iteration technique when converting an array into another structure is to use reduction:

```js
const arr = [
    {"id": "1", "text": "AAA", "category": "food", "value": "1"},
    {"id": "2", "text": "BBB", "category": "food", "value": "2"},
    {"id": "3", "text": "CCC", "category": "drinks", "value": "3"}
]

const result = arr.reduce((hash, item) => {
  if (!hash.hasOwnProperty(item.category)) {
    hash[item.category] = []
  }
  hash[item.category].push(item)
  return hash
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var res_data = [
    {"id": "1", "text": "AAA", "category": "food", "value": "1"},
    {"id": "2", "text": "BBB", "category": "food", "value": "2"},
    {"id": "3", "text": "CCC", "category": "drinks", "value": "3"}
];

var result = {};
for(var i = 0; i < res_data.length; i++){
  if(result[res_data[i].category] == undefined)
    result[res_data[i].category] = [];
  result[res_data[i].category].push(res_data[i])
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a valid output, you can use the function `reduce`.

```js
var data = [    {"id": "1", "text": "AAA", "category": "food", "value": "1"},    {"id": "2", "text": "BBB", "category": "food", "value": "2"},    {"id": "3", "text": "CCC", "category": "drinks", "value": "3"}],
    result = data.reduce((a, c) => {
      (a[c.category] || (a[c.category] = [])).push(c);
      return a;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var res_data = [
    {"id": "1", "text": "AAA", "category": "food", "value": "1"},
    {"id": "2", "text": "BBB", "category": "food", "value": "2"},
    {"id": "3", "text": "CCC", "category": "drinks", "value": "3"}
];

function filter(arr, key, value) {
    var res = [];
    for(var x = 0, max = arr.length; x < max; x = x + 1) {
        if(typeof arr[x] === 'object' && arr[x].hasOwnProperty(key) && arr[x][key] === value) {
            res.push(arr[x]);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Then you can filter by any property like this:

```
filter(res_data, 'category', 'food');
```

It will return:

```
[
    {"id": "1", "text": "AAA", "category": "food", "value": "1"},
    {"id": "2", "text": "BBB", "category": "food", "value": "2"}
]
```